# How to reload all bash startup files in os x?

Tags: bash

I could reload them in this order http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/ with `source`, but there is a short way?

I mean, a command that loads all files in its order, and not to do:

```
source /etc/profile
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_login
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "is there a short way" to reload?  If you're modifying your shell environment typically you modified the appropriate files (like .bash_login or .bash_rc) then you just type "source ~/.bash_rc".  It's only one short command unless I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Why would you want to source ~/.bash_logout if you weren't actually logging out? Also, ordinarily, you wouldn't source `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, and `.profile` in the same session.

Comment: edited: removed `~/.bash_logout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.bashrc`

```
rld() {
  source /etc/profile
  source ~/.bash_profile
  source ~/.bashrc
  source ~/.bash_login
  source ~/.profile
}
```

Now you can go `rld` whenever you want to reload all those files.

Answer (score 7):

It may not be the best, but here is a quick way to resource everything:

```
exec bash -l
```

The `-l` forces bash to work as a login shell, which should source /etc/profile.

Comment: this is good but it changes my prompt to `bash-3.2$`, how do I recover my previous prompt?

Comment: @juanpastas: Where is your prompt being set? It should be a line that says `PS1=`

Comment: I updated the answer, but it might not work, since `/etc/bashrc` isn't source by bash by default. If `/etc/bashrc` is source in `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` then it should work. Please let me know the result.

Comment: I used it with `-l` but doesn't reload the files